# Linq Query for Adding Values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list which contains a model with values

```
The Values : 
Month           TotalMarks
May                60
May                70
May                80
June               60
July               80
```

I need a query which adds up all the duplicate month values and stores in another list of the same model

Comment: `GroupBy` month and then `Sum` them

Comment: ok inside foreach ?

Comment: @VishrutPatil, no, you no need a loop, look at answer

Comment: @VishrutPatil, No loop needed someone already provided the answer

Comment: I am new to linq so my first way was to use a foreach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
marks
    .GroubBy(x => x.Month)
    .Select(g => new EntitiyType
    {
        Month = g.Key,
        TotalMarks = g.Sum(x => x.TotalMarks)
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Month)
    .ToList();
```